# Проброс порта через конфликтующую подсеть

Tags: linux, маршрутизация, iptables

Внешний ИП (микротик) 192.168.0.1 ->eth0 хост 192.168.0.3  ... usb0 -> 192.168.0.1 другой роутер.

На микротике просто DNAT 192.168.0.3. Этого должно хватить.

Делаю петельку на netns и nat

```
ip netns add TESTA
ip link add name ve0a type veth peer name ve0b
ip link set dev ve0b netns TESTA
ip link set dev usb0 netns TESTA

ip link set dev ve0a up
ip a a 172.16.0.1/30 dev ve0a

ip netns exec TESTA ip link set dev ve0b up
ip netns exec TESTA ip a a 172.16.0.2/30 dev ve0b
ip netns exec TESTA dhclient usb0

ip netns exec TESTA sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

ip netns exec TESTA iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 172.16.0.2 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1
ip netns exec TESTA iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.1/32 -j MASQUERADE

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.0.3 -p tcp --dport 28001 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.16.0.2:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 172.16.0.2/32 -j MASQUERADE
```

Что забыл?

```
Подключение к ip:28001... ошибка: В соединении отказано.
```

На 172.16.0.2 открывается с основного неймспейса, с внешки не открывает..

Answer (score 0):

Всё работает. Правило в форварде на первом роутере.